# Bootstrap - having one column in a row with horizontal scroll instead of wrapping onto the next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I am trying to create page which is divided into 2 sections (using columns). In the left hand side column (first outer column) I want to have other columns nested inside (inner column x).

I am trying to make it so that if there are more than 12 inner columns in the first outer column, they don't wrap onto the next line - rather the outer column which contains them has a horizontal scroll.

Here is the code I have, however my inner columns still wrap onto the next line:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-9">
   <h4>first outter column (trying to get this column to be scroll-able instead of wrap onto next line)</h4>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div><b>inner column 1</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div><b>inner column 2</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div><b>inner column 3</b></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div><b>inner column 4</b></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
    <h4>second outter column</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS I am using to make it more clear:

```
.col-md-9 {
 background-color: red;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow-x: auto;
 }

 .col-md-3 {
 background-color: yellow;
 }

 .col-md-4 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner columns should be wrapped in another `.row`. Then add a `flex` class to prevent the columns from wrapping using flexbox...

```
 .flex {
     display: flex;
 }
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/zJB4GkMC44

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h4>first outter column (trying to get this column to be scroll-able instead of wrap onto next line)</h4>
            <div class="row flex">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div><b>inner column 1</b></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div><b>inner column 2</b></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div><b>inner column 3</b></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div><b>inner column 4</b></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>second outter column</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Note:** This layout would simplified in **Bootstrap 4** since flexbox is included: https://www.codeply.com/go/f4XKDAKLHq You would just need to use the `flex-nowrap` class.

Comment: Hm, I can see that it is working perfectly as I need in the codeply link you gave me but for some reason it is not working the same in my own code editor and the inner columns still wrap onto the next line :/ - your link however does exactly what I wanted it to so I will accept this as the answer and keep trying. Thank you